# Filter out a specific member of a dimension hierarchy in MDX query

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I am pretty new to MDX and I have written a basic MDX query which returns a measure as well as full hierarchy of my product dimension:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Amount]} on 0,
{
DESCENDANTS([ProductH].[ProductH], [ProductH].[ProductH].[Lvl4], LEAVES)
}
ON 1
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    {StrToSet('[AccountH].[AccountH].[Lvl1].&[TST17:0]',CONSTRAINED)} ON COLUMNS
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      {StrToSet('[ProductH].[ProductH].[All]',CONSTRAINED)} ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Model]
  )
)
```

This returns the result set for my SSRS report which is basically the amount for all levels in product dimension for the user's chosen account hierarchy

Now, I want to exclude from this set the amounts under the 2nd level of account hierarchy with the specific name "Exclude".
I've managed to add this filter using crossjoin and except - based on account node's unique name:

```
[AccountH].[AccountH].[Lvl2].&[TST17:0]&[TST17:1000]
```

but I want specifically to filter out based on the shown name, remove amounts where:

```
[AccountH].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION = "Exclude"
```

How do I filter out based on hierarchy node's name?

Comment: did you try the filter function?

Comment: Yes both its the same problem, it seems like I cannot specify the name of the node there, when I do the node is not removed

Answer (score 0):

The Where clause must be enough:

```
select
...
from [Model]
where ({[AccountH].[AccountH].Members - [AccountH].[AccountH].[Exclude]})
```

Comment: AccountH is a hierarchy, i cannot get the "exclude" member by just using its visible name as I understand

Comment: Why not? Try: select {[AccountH].[AccountH].Members - [AccountH].[AccountH].[Exclude]} on 0 from [Model]

Comment: select [AccountH].[AccountH].[Exclude] works, I get a member with that name. However the removal of the member does not work, I've tried both your version and the .[Lvl2] specification...

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out with some help, "Exclude" account nodes are not unique in the hierarchy, even on the same level (level2 for me), so apperently removing them with EXCEPT() does not work.
This works however:

```
Filter([AccountH].[AccountH].[Lvl2]].Members
      ,[AccountH].[AccountH].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION <> "Exclude")
```

since it checks the name. But apperently the filter function is a slow one so Im going with a cross join Account * Product and then removing the "Exclude" accounts in SSRS report